# created symlink using npm install on the vagrant machine which is hosted on centos7 but facing issues during buid from package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, vagrant, centos7

I was trying to install and build a project from package.json using npm. And it is a vagrant machine with centos7. I faced issues with npm install due to symlinks so used **npm install --no-bin-links** and packages got installed but later faced an issue during build using command  **sudo npm run build** where my package.json file has

"start": "react-app-rewired start",
"build": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=16384 build",

and the error is react-app-rewired command not found . Going through some suggestions on google added the below line to vagrant file

v.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate//", "1"]

The symlinks are created under the .bin folder in the node_modules folder when I ran npm install

but now when I ran **sudo npm run build** I get the below error

sh: /home/vagrant/UI/node_modules/.bin/react-app-rewired: Permission denied

when I check permissions on the folder .bin using **ls -ld .bin**  following are the permissions

drwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant 524288 Oct 19 13:22 node_modules

And when I check to see permissions using **ls-l react-app-rewired** on react-app-rewired following are the permissions

lrw-rw-rw-. 1 vagrant vagrant 0 Oct 19 13:22 react-app-rewired -> ../react-app-rewired/bin/index.js

can you help me in building the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by making changes to package.json. I replaced react-app-rewired in scripts with node ./node_modules/react-app-rewired/bin/index.js and react-scripts with node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js